# datepicker issue with jquery on textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using "jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js" file in my project.
I have the following code in aspx page

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
        $('#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>').datepicker();
        });

</script>
```

**add file reference**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/script/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js") %>" ></script>
```

but I dont know where I am wrong. Plz help me out to resolve this issue.

I found this kind of error

[image: jquery error in error console]

Comment: Can you post the image of your solution explorer where you pasted the scripts

Comment: Replace this `<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/script/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js") %>" ></script>` with `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js` and make a try

Comment: Try this `$('#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>').datepick();` you can try this jquery http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing Jquery file add any jquery file (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) before use datepicker :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/script/jquery-latest.js") %>" ></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've included the jQuery ui, but not jQuery itsself. You need a script tag to include jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/script/jqueryfilenamehere.js") %>" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/script/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js") %>" ></script>
```

Comment: where i need to script tag. plz define.

Comment: You need to add a script tag for jquery before your jquery ui tag

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you are add Jquery.js Reference

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/script/jquery-latest.js") %>" ></script>
```

If you are using master page concept in asp.net or your jquery.js file is in master page then make sure you add: Page.Header.DataBind(); and Page.DataBind(); to the PageLoad() event of the Master page.

Answer (score 0):

You forgotten to include jquery: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
jquery-ui doesn't include automatically jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Include reference to jQuery Library.
You may use from Google Hosted Libraries as follows;

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```